# Quantum Chemistry Laptop

Tags: laptop, linux, windows

I'd like to have a Laptop that can do some QC calculations which is able to even do a little heavier stuff.

Such calculations need a fast CPU, don't use hyperthreading, have either a high memory demand or a high hard drive I/O.

So for the last point, SSDs are not the way to go, right? Probably some mixed system with SSD for system and HDD for the writing stuff.

Let's ignore the price - are there laptops that can deal with such specifications?

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recs! I have a few questions regarding your requirements. Do you need a hard drive with fast I/O, or do you need a ton of storage (<= 1TB)? I also am assuming that the calculations are not multi-threaded, based on your hyper-threading comment. Is this correct? Is there anything else that you can add to the question to make it more specific? Things like "high memory demand" and "high hard drive I/O" are vague. Thanks!

Comment: Thx :) Hard drive should be fast and large. ;) Though I guess something between 512G and 1T is enough, where the latter could be external for saving purposes only. Calculations would be in parallel, using multiple cores if available but would not need/profit from hyperthreading. High memory demand means s.th. like at least 16G, better 32G in total. High hard drive I/O means that whatever can't get written into the memory would get written on the disc and read in again when needed. These files can get several GB large and that of course takes some time to write and read with slow hard drives.

Comment: More details are needed. How many cores do you really need? Any GPU acceleration is needed or possible?
You might want to consider waiting for AMD based laptops with more cores (or Intel equivalent, when they release their counter chips)

Comment: @eddr depends ... let's say 1-4/1-8. On the cluster I use 1 to 24. GPU is not important, thus the Nvidia Tesla or whatever the name for laptops would be is not what I need. At least not now. Are there information about the future AMD chips that you refer to?

Comment: @eddr is probably talking about the AMD Threadripper chips (and maybe Ryzen and Epyc as well). Threadripper is the high-core count high-end desktop processor segment of the new AMD processors (with a lot of raw power that you probably could use here) and Ryzen is the gamer version (cheaper, less cores, like 8 instead of 16) and Epyc is the server-line. Actually ASUS claims to have an 8-core Ryzen laptop in the pipeline and will release it "later this summer".

Answer (score 2):

First, I'll post the solution which may not directly fit your needs, but could at least be worth a consideration and will probably deliver significantly higher performance, however
you'll essentially be getting a highly portable desktop PC, so you need:

- A monitor wherever you go
- A mouse
- A keyboard

If you are actually in a situation where you can have these (easily?) available where you go (and note that there are modern variants of all of these designed for high mobility), I can recommend (even though I did not actually test / own one):

### [The Titan X179 Workstation](http://www.titancomputers.com/Titan-X179-Intel-Xeon-E5-V4-Broadwell-EP-Ultra-p/x179.htm)

Why does it fit your needs?
**Because it runs workstation / server-grade equipment in a very compact case!**

Up to:

- Just about any [Intel Xeon E5 v4](https://ark.intel.com/products/series/91287/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-v4-Family) (Codename: Broadwell-EP), [up to 22 physical cores](https://ark.intel.com/products/91317/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2699-v4-55M-Cache-2_20-GHz), will just about blow everything else mobile out of the window (you may want to know that the Xeon is fastering than everything else because of *parallelism*, the actual cores have quite a low base-clock and architecturally are also 2 generations behind as of now, which amounts to a few per cent performance difference)
- 16, 32, 64 or 128 GB [Error-Checking and Correcting Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory) (a Xeon-only feature that you may not need)
- Up to 6TB of Samsung Pro-branded SSD storage (2x SATA, 1x M.2), also note that the M.2 SSD has a [1.2PBW / 5yr warranty policy](http://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-960-pro-m-2-2tb-mz-v6p2t0bw/) (that is they guarantee that it will work for 5 years or 1.2 *Peta*-bytes written, whichever happens first) and the SATA SSD has a at least a [300TBW / 10yr warranty policy](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/service/warranty/MZ-7KE2T0BW).

Comment: "don't use hyperthreading". The 22 cores will be useless if OP means the applications are single threaded.

Comment: @RubyJunk to quote the OP from the comments under the question: _"Calculations would be in parallel, using multiple cores if available but would not need/profit from hyperthreading"_  and _"On the cluster I use 1 to 24"_ as the answer to _"how many cores do you really need"_. So yes, the OP _can_ make use of these cores (and in fact does when he can), and in fact his computations are so intense that Hyperthreading (which exploits not fully utilized functional units in cores to deal with other processes) essentially would have little room to serve other cores / the application.

Comment: I understand now. I didn't realize OP commented below and that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

Now for the more traditional approach: You want a CPU-heavy *actual* laptop with a decent amount of fast storage and quite a bit of RAM. So the obvious solution is to look for the beefiest CPU that can be crammed into a laptop and go from there. Normally people would just look for laptop CPUs here, but because Gamers being Gamers, *there are laptops that use Desktop CPUs* which of course are much better performance-wise due to higher peak clocks (but of course cooling and power consumption tend to make such laptops hot, loud and with short battery lifetime).

So my recommendation will be:

### [The Origin PC EON17-X](https://www.originpc.com/gaming/laptops/eon17-x/)

Which features (up to)

- An Intel Core i7-7700K (Codename: Kaby Lake), with 4 physical cores and remarkably high clock rates (meaning these cores will be *very* fast and much faster individually [than the Xeon cores from my other answer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7826/273)) and notably, this is a desktop CPU, so you should a) be able to actually overclock it if you so want and b) it is allowed to produce much more heat and thus stay at higher clocks for longer.
- 64 GB of (non-ECC) RAM
- If I'm parsing the configuration page right, up to *four* 2TB Samsung Pro SSDs (2x M.2 and 2x SATA), [comments from my other answer apply.](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7826/273)

Comment: Why should/would I go with this instead of a dedicated workstation laptop like the Lenovo Thinkpad P70?

Comment: @pH13-YetanotherPhilipp Because the P70 runs a either a laptop i7 or a Xeon-turned laptop i7 (roughly speaking) but in either case the CPU may only take up to 45W whereas the Origin PC's CPU may take up to 91W (allowing for higher clocks for longer).